# C++ Partial specialization friend declaration - template Matrix class

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, operator-overloading

I've created a matrix class as below:

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned M>
class Matrix {
public:

    template <unsigned P>
    Matrix<T,N,P> operator*(const Matrix<T,M,P>& other) const {
        Matrix<T,N,P> result;

        for(auto i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for(auto j = 0; j < P; j++) {
                for(auto k = 0; k < M; k++) {
                    result.data[i][j] += data[i][k] * other.data[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

/* ... other members ... */

private:
    std::array<std::array<T, M>, N> data;
};
```

The problem I have right now, is that I can not access `other.data` because it's a private member of another class (other dimensions). What I tried was to declare the `operator*` as a non-member friend like this:

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned M>
class Matrix {
public:
    template <typename Type, unsigned RowA, unsigned ColA, unsigned ColB>
    Matrix<Type, RowA, ColB> friend operator*(const Matrix<Type, RowA, ColA>& a, const Matrix<Type, RowA, ColB>& b);

/* ... */

};

template <typename Type, unsigned RowA, unsigned ColA, unsigned ColB>
Matrix<Type, RowA, ColB>  operator*(const Matrix<Type, RowA, ColA>& a, const Matrix<Type, RowA, ColB>& b) {
    Matrix<Type, RowA, ColB> result;

    for(auto i = 0; i < RowA; i++) {
        for(auto j = 0; j < ColB; j++) {
            for(auto k = 0; k < ColA; k++) {
                result.data[i][j] += a.data[i][k] * b.data[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

but it doesn't work - compiler complains that it cannot find a valid overload for `operator*`.

What are my other options here? The solution would be to declare all matrices with compatible dimensions as friends, but that would be partial template specialization which as far as i know is not possible. Something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned M>
class Matrix {
public:
    template<typename P>
    friend class Matrix<T,P,N>;
    
    /* ... */
};
```

I can not change the way I store data or `Matrix` template arguments - that's an assignment I was given.

Answer (score 1):

> What are my other options here?

IMHO, your best option is add a public access method, for matrix, as follows

```
T const & at (unsigned i, unsigned j) const // <-- read only version
 { return data[i][j]; }                     //     for const objects

T & at (unsigned i, unsigned j) // <-- read and write version
 { return data[i][j]; }
```

so the core of your `operator*()` (external version) become

```
result.at(i, j) += a.at(i, k) * b.at(k, j);
```

and there is no needs of declare `friend` nothing.

Anyway, the signature of your external `operator*()` is wrong: should be

```
template <typename T, unsigned Row, unsigned Mid, unsigned Col>
Matrix<T, Row, Col>  operator* (Matrix<T, Row, Mid> const & a,
                                Matrix<T, Mid, Col> const & b)
```

You're using `RowA`, instead of `ColA`, for the first dimension in your second argument.

Comment: That's certainly the easiest way, thanks. My whole assignment is focused on class templates and friends, that's why I focused so much on trying to solve it that way.